# Compare-Object different property names

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to use Compare-Object -property, for comparing 2 properties with different names? I have something like this:

```
    $ComparisonProperty= $ComparisonProperty | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Url -Value ITEM_TARGET_URI -PassThru
Compare-Object $FirstFile $SecondFile -Property Url -PassThru | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Out-file .\result.txt
```

But this gives an error:

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null

At $ComparisonProperty

//Edit

Sample data are 2 csv files with many headers, 1 with Url header in it, another with ITEM_TARGET_URI in it. Result should be strings from file 1 that do not exist in file 2. Comparison works if i provide them with the same property names, but the whole point is to force it to compare 2 properties with different names.

Comment: Should't it be `$ComparisonProperty | Add-Member ...` -> `$SecondFile | Add-Member ...`? (assuming `$SecondFile` is the one without the `Url` property)

Comment: To the title I say use a property alias or create a calculated property to make the properties have the same name. Your error though does not really have anything to do with that. Is `$ComparisonProperty` declared anywhere else? Else I agree with the error. Is is $null. Which file does not have the "right" property

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That is the answer here. Wolwgang.. this question would be better if you showed some sample data and expected output. Then the answer would have something to work with better.

Comment: @Matt  Done, provided some more data what am i trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you know the headers ahead of time and do the other columns matter in the ouput?

Comment: @Matt I know their names ahead of time, and other columns do not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the actual question calculated properties or property aliases would get you what you need. You have been trying to use the latter but you need to add the property to the file object itself. Consider the two file examples

```
id,first_name
1,Elia
2,Nikolos
3,Bert
4,Sharleen
5,Bill

id,beginning_name
1,Elia
2,Nikolos
3,Bert
4,Mildrid
5,Bill
```

Notice that the headers are different. So now lets try and create the property alias. Assume that I have already imported these files as CSV's

```
$file2 | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name first_name -Value beginning_name
compare-object $file1 $file2 -Property first_name
```

That will give you the results you were expecting. I added an alias to the second file *object*

### You could just work with column data

Another approach to this is to drop the properties and just work with string arrays. Since I know the headers I want I can just get those columns themselves as well

```
$namesfromfile1 = $file1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty first_name
$namesfromfile2 = $file2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty beginning_name

Compare-Object $urls1 $urls2
```

Depending on your PS version this can also be shortened. Whether or not its simplified is up to the reader.

```
Compare-Object ($file1).first_name ($file2).beginning_name
```